# Right-align column headings in lightning:datatable

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm using a lightning:datatable to retreive data and want the date-formatted columns to be right-aligned.  I've figured out how to right-align the actual data, but the column heading is still left-aligned and I can't find any documentation on how to right-align the heading to match the data alignment.

datatable definition:

```
<lightning:datatable
            keyField="id"
            data="{! v.eeObject.serviceBranches }"
            columns="{! v.serviceColumns }"
            hideCheckboxColumn="true"/>
```

column definition extract:

```
component.set('v.serviceColumns', [
{label: 'Entry Date', fieldName: 'serviceEntryDate', type: 'date-local', 
typeAttributes:{ month: "numeric", day: "numeric" }, cellAttributes: { alignment: 'right' }}
```

]);

As you'll see in the screenshot, the dates right-align as expected but the column heading is still left-aligned.  I haven't found anything in the documentation that explains how to right-align the heading to match.

[image: Left-aligned heading, right-aligned data]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and, while I could not find conclusive evidence to this, concluded that it is simply not possible. This is reinforced by the fact that Salesforce doesn't right-align neither their number/date fields nor their titles on the standard listviews (see image).

Short of convoluted CSS (which I wouldn't recommend as it can easily break with upgrades) I don't see how you could do this natively.

[image: Campaigns sample image]

PS: I would normally put this as a comment since it is not great as an answer. But I have an image that I want to convey so an answer it is.